# JQuery event binding with ['data-href'] selector not working

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-selectors

I have some code like below

```
$("html").on("change", "input['data-href']", function() {
  var href, obj, params;
  obj = $(this);
  href = obj.attr('data-href');
  params = {};
  params[obj.attr('data-param')] = obj.val();
  return $.post(href, params);
});
```

The intention is that I can use form elements anywhere and have them auto
submit their value via ajax to the specified URL. However that is irrelevant
to the problem. The problem is that the code is detecting the change event
on any **input** element and not only elements with matching selector **input['data-href']**

Is there some subtle issue with **$().on** that I am not addressing?

Comment: $("your selector goes here").on("event goes here", "args as json passed to the callback here", callback_function_here);

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe. Please check the docs again... You're wrong. `.on(
    events [, selector] [, data], handler(eventObject) )`

Comment: Can you point out the link to the docs that you're checking? I'm checking at http://api.jquery.com/on/ and if you look the examples it's kind of like I'm saying.. maybe I'm looking at the wrong section?

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe. It's right in the top. Can't give you more than that.

Comment: Ok, I'm wrong then... I was mistaking it with other method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Attribute names may not be quoted. Use:

```
$("html").on("change", "input[data-href]", function() {
```

When your attribute contains special characters, a double slash can be used to escape it:

```
$("element[namespace\\:attribute]")
```

Comment: I suspect this is the right answer. No idea why I quoted it in the code cause when I was testing in the console I never put them in. Total blindness to an obvious typo. Strange though why it matches more rather than nothing at all.

Answer (score 2):

The `name` of the attribute does **not** go within quotes (double or single), the `value` does. If you're checking just for the presence of the attribute, you want `[data-href]` rather than `['data-href']`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this you can simply use $(".data\-href").change(function(){}).